# Eclipse workspace issue with CCRC plugin error

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, clearcase-remote-client

**Update 28 May 2013:**

I have found a work around for this. Though this is not always works MOST of the time it does.
In Eclipse > Preferences > General > Startup and Shutdown
uncheck the option "ClearCase Remote Client plug-in"

Every time I start the problem workspace, before doing anything (like click on any resource or click on project in project explorer) I connect to the ClearCase repository.
This seems to calm down the error most of the time. Also, the Eclipse shortcut that I have on my desktop, has -clean option set in it. So when I start the eclipse my eclipse already starts with the clean up option. Though not sure if it has any bearing on the problem.
However not sure if this will help in a situation when I am working offline; when I can not connect to the ClearCase repository.

**Update 21 May 2013:**

At this time it looks like there is no resolution for this except a CCRC plugin upgrade.
For now marking VonC's answer as correct. Will update the post if I find a better solution.

I created a fresh new workspace and setup the workspace and so far I do not see any problems so far. Still not sure what was wrong with my workspace though.

==================================================

I have been having this problem for quite sometime on one of the workspace.

**Error:**

I am seeing the following error pop up with the error message; and will NOT go away.

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
Could not initialize class com.ibm.rational.team.client.ui.model.common.ImageManager
```

**Symptoms:**

1. It happens only in one work space almost all the time.
2. Every time I restart this workspace, when ever I click on any projects in project explorer or any open file, it causes the error pop up to come up.
3. It goes away if I close all files, close the offending project and then delete the project. I fire up eclipse, re-import the project and the issue goes away only as long as I continue using the eclipse. Once I restart the eclipse the same problem persists.

**What I have tried so far:**

1. start eclipse with -clean option --> It does not solve the problem.
2. I have enabled the "Refresh workspace on startup" option in "Eclipse > Preferences > General > Startup and Shutdown" --> this does not solve theproblem.
3. I deleted the folder "org.eclipse.core.resources" under "Offending_Workspace > .metadata > .plugins" folder --> this has no effect. The problem persists as mentioned in Symptoms3 above.

**System Info:**

> Windows 7 Enterprise Edition 64 bit.
>
> Eclipse 3.7 Java EE developers
>
> CCRC plugin Version: 7.1.0.0 , Build id: 7.1.1.03.00_2010C.D100803

Is there anything that can be done to resolve this. It's frustrating to work with such a broken plugin, that practically hinders ones work.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Interesting. I have included your workaround in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like [PM38965](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM38965) and there is no other solution than upgrading:

> A fix is available in ClearCase versions 7.1.1.8, 7.1.2.5 and 8.0.0.1

You can see it listed in [this release note](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/rational/clearcase/7.1.2/7.1.2.5-RATL-RCC/7.1.2.5-RATL-RCC-WIN-FP05.txt):

#### PM38965:

> Addresses a ClearCase issue where the ClearTeam Explorer produces a "`Could not initialize class com.ibm.rational.team.client.ui.model.common.ImageManager`" error intermittently when performing various operations.

---

The OP reports a workaround:

In `Eclipse > Preferences > General > Startup and Shutdown`, uncheck the option "`ClearCase Remote Client plug-in`"

> Every time I start the problem workspace, before doing anything (like click on any resource or click on project in project explorer) I connect to the ClearCase repository.
>   This seems to calm down the error most of the time.
>
> Also, the Eclipse shortcut that I have on my desktop, has '`-clean`' option set in it. So when I start the eclipse my eclipse already starts with the clean up option.
>   Though not sure if it has any bearing on the problem. However not sure if this will help in a situation when I am working offline; when I can not connect to the ClearCase repository.

The '`-clean`' being a local operation, it will have the same effect offline or online.

Comment: thanks. I think I had seen this on one of the IBM sites. The problem is the clearcase plugin update site is maintained by the enterprise team and it will not be updated anytime soon. also if I am not wrong the plugin version is also constrained by the clearcase server version as well. Am I right?

Comment: @Ayusman yes, CCRC upgrade is directly linked to the CCRC server.

Comment: alright. I guess I am stuck with the problem right now... will see if it changes